# Elasticsearch - with or without a "doc."?

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, nest

I'm facing some strange issue with "doc." keyword on Nest C# Elasticsearch.
I'm using Couchbase, and I have a class where one of its fields is an array of objects
I try to search inside this array for a specific value.
Something like this:

```
        string mailFilesKey = string.Empty;
        ISearchResponse<object> result = _mainManager.Client.Search<object>(c => c
        .Type("MailFiles")
        .Query(q =>
            q.Term("SentFile_Id", fileId))
        .Size(1));
```

Now, this thing actually works. But when I do this one, it doesn't work:

```
     q.Term("doc.SentFile_Id", fileId))
```

Why?

Comment: It depends entirely on the mapping. If `SentFile_Id` is not contained by an "object" or "nested" type named `doc`, then it will not work _with_ `doc.` as a prefix. Presumably since it works, you are not containing it within a `doc`.

Comment: The patient says, "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." The doctor replies, "Then don't do that!"

Comment: use http://www.telerik.com/fiddler and check what query nest fires to elastic search and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haha ok nice one. I had this thing long time ago when i started to use Nest and elastic. If you have the object then you can use lambda expressions
like `f=>f.SentFile_Id`.
Now when you use a string to get the name of the field in nest you must know that all fields, index name, types in elastic are stored with lowercase first letter. So you should use this : `q.Term("sentFile_Id", fileId))`
Should work just fine.